# Jsonを取得した後に、Jsonのデータを複数のテキストボックスに分割したい

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest

まず、現在のJson取得ソースは下記のようになっており

```
$.get(url, { id: name }, function (data) {
    $("#textbox").val(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

直接Jsonデータを１つのtextboxに出力していますが、
取得したJsonデータを複数のテキストボックスに出力したいです。

具体的には、
Jsonのデータの内容は下記のように「ID・Name・Email」の３項目で、それぞれを別のテキストボックスに出力したいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

```
{"ID":1,"Name":"Taro","Email":"test.taro@sample.jp"}
```

ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんな感じでしょうか？引数の`data`は`Object`と推測しました。

```
$.get(url, { id: name }, function (data) {
    $("#textbox-ID").val(data.id);
    $("#textbox-Name").val(data.Name);
    $("#textbox-Email").val(data.Email);
});
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決することが出来ました。